# mat-select-search doesn't load initial list

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular9

i am doing mat-select-search  with this [example](https://stackblitz.com/github/Wurthma/ExampleNgxMatSelectSearch?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-search%2Fselect-search.component.html) .
i am using reactive forms, with dynamic data. my response from server is just array of items.
i have dynamic data vehicles, when i type  in search it works but initial list doesn't show.
how can i make my dynamic data show for the first time?

**.ts**

```
 vehicles = [];
  public filteredOptions: ReplaySubject<any[]> = new ReplaySubject<any[]>(1);
  protected _onDestroy = new Subject<void>();
  @Output() onSelectionChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

public modelFilterCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();

   @ViewChild('multiSelect', { static: true }) multiSelect: MatSelect;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.campaignService.getVehicles().subscribe((data: any[])=>{
      this.vehicles = data;
    })

    this.modelFilterCtrl.valueChanges
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.filterEntities();
    });

}

set data(data: any[]) {
    this._data = data;
    // load the initial list
    this.filteredOptions.next(this.data.slice());
  }
  get data(): any[] {
    return this._data;
  }
  private _data: any[];

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.setInitialValue();
  }

  onChange($event) {
    this.onSelectionChange.emit($event);
  }

  private setInitialValue() {
    this.filteredOptions
      .pipe(take(1), takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
      .subscribe(() => {
        if(this.multiSelect)
          this.multiSelect.compareWith = (a: any, b: any) => a === b;
      });
  }
```

**.html**

```
 <mat-select multiple formControlName="Brand" (selectionChange)="onChange($event)" #multiSelect>
      <mat-option>
        <ngx-mat-select-search
        [formControl]="modelFilterCtrl"
        [placeholderLabel]="'Search...'">
      </ngx-mat-select-search>
      </mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredOptions | async" [value]="item">{{item}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize `filteredOptions` when you get the initial vehicules list :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.campaignService.getVehicles().subscribe((data: any[])=>{
      this.vehicles = data;
      this.filteredOptions.next(this.vehicles);
    })
```